# nextcloud on docker - error initializing database

Tags: mysql, docker, nextcloud

When starting my nextcloud container with `docker-compose up` I encounter the error:

```
db_1_7bb6e5f5b725 | Initializing database
db_1_7bb6e5f5b725 | mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql': Permission denied
db_1_7bb6e5f5b725 | Fatal error Can't create database directory '/var/lib/mysql//mysql'
db_1_7bb6e5f5b725 | 
db_1_7bb6e5f5b725 | The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
db_1_7bb6e5f5b725 | https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
test_db_1_7bb6e5f5b725 exited with code 1
```

The specified docker-compose looks like:

```
version: '2'

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    user: www-data
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=***
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    restart: always
```

Comment: In your `db` container, does the `www-data` user have write access to `/var/lib/mysql` on the docker volume named `db`?

Comment: @GracefulRestart Do do I check that in the container? When exiting `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/bash` I get the response container restarting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the [official `mariadb` Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb), the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script requires the path `/var/lib/mysql` to be writable by the user you are running the container as.  Otherwise, a container will not start

In your `docker-compose.yml`, you have defined a named volume `db` that is to be mounted to the `db` container.  If you are not creating the `db` named volume before executing `docker-compose up`, then the `/var/lib/mysql` directory within the volume likely is being created with incorrect permissions as you are normally a privileged user when running `docker-compose`.

You should always be able to examine the volume from the host, you may also be able to mount the volume to a new container as read-only to look at it (minimal or blank image works best).  From the host, you can run `docker volume inspect db` to get the file location respective to the host, run `docker volume list` to see if docker-compose named the volume differently.  If you do not have an exotic file backend, you should be able to directly `chown` the necessary directories to the UID of the user from within the container.

All of this should be done before you attempt to run the `docker-compose` cluster, by creating the `db` named volume first and making sure the necessary directories have the proper permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. The question is how/where do I create the db volume?

Comment: [`docker volume create db`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/).  Then `docker volume inspect db` to find out where it is and `chown` it to the proper UID.

Comment: The dockerfile isn't stored locally - where do I add these changes?
I put it in the initfile before docker-comose up is called. Still got permission denied error. `docker volume inspect db` shows the volume.

Comment: if you can see the volume from `docker volume inspect db` are you then able to change the ownership to the user that will run in the container?

Comment: I solved the problem, by setting the volumes in my docker-compose locally and cleaning the docker volumes with `docker volume prune`.

But thanks fo your help. :)